# не запускает exe-файл

Tags: windows, windows-10, xamarin

пытаюсь запустить exe-файл программки написанной в 17-й visual studio на xamarin. Реакции никакой, от имени админа так же. Операционка винда 10

В просмотре событий, в журнале приложений вылетают ошибки такого содержания:

> Приложение: CameraXamarin.UWP.exe Версия платформы: v4.0.30319
>   Описание. Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения.
>   Сведения об исключении: код исключения e0434352, адрес исключения
>   00007FF8F542A839 Стек:
>
> Имя сбойного приложения: CameraXamarin.UWP.exe, версия: 1.0.0.0, метка
>   времени: 0x5e610dd7 Имя сбойного модуля: KERNELBASE.dll, версия:
>   10.0.18362.628, метка времени: 0xf96f12ee Код исключения: 0xe0434352 Смещение ошибки: 0x000000000003a839 Идентификатор сбойного процесса:
>   0x2c54 Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d5f3907dbce14f Путь
>   сбойного приложения:
>   D:\Projects\CameraXamarin\CameraXamarin\CameraXamarin.UWP\bin\x64\Debug\CameraXamarin.UWP.exe
>   Путь сбойного модуля: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Идентификатор
>   отчета: e3495712-9927-487b-9edc-0be6fdfe122e Полное имя сбойного
>   пакета:  Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:
>
> Контейнер ошибки 1952069380794768682, тип 4 Имя события: APPCRASH
>   Отклик: Нет данных Идентификатор CAB: 0
>
> Сигнатура проблемы: P1: CameraXamarin.UWP.exe P2: 1.0.0.0 P3: 5e610dd7
>   P4: KERNELBASE.dll P5: 10.0.18362.628 P6: f96f12ee P7: e0434352 P8:
>   000000000003a839 P9:  P10:
>
> Вложенные файлы:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER762B.tmp.dmp
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7745.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7765.tmp.xml
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7765.tmp.csv
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER7786.tmp.txt
>
> Эти файлы можно найти здесь:
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_CameraXamarin.UW_339adde5306ae96cb3a38d5215266fe877b48_3c8816d1_f21df3e4-703a-40d6-ae04-7da78497b14d
>
> Символ анализа:  Повторный поиск решения: 0 Идентификатор отчета:
>   e3495712-9927-487b-9edc-0be6fdfe122e Состояние отчета: 268435456
>   Хэшированный контейнер: 62bf4c6a4781ac4cbb1724c263305d2a Идентификатор
>   GUID CAB: 0

кто сталкивался с подобным, как можно решить эту проблему?

---

сам код:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Button takePhotoBtn = new Button { Text = "Сделать фото" };
            Button getPhotoBtn = new Button { Text = "Выбрать фото" };
            Image img = new Image();

            //выбор фото
            getPhotoBtn.Clicked += async (o, e) =>
            {
                if (CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {
                    MediaFile photo = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                    img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(photo.Path);
                }
            };

            //съемка фото
            takePhotoBtn.Clicked += async (o, e) =>
            {
                if (CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable && CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        SaveToAlbum = true,
                        Directory = "Sample",
                        Name = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh.mm.ss")}.jpg"
                    });

                    if (file == null)
                        return;

                    img.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
                }
            };
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new StackLayout
                    {
                         Children = {takePhotoBtn, getPhotoBtn},
                         Orientation =StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                         HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                    },
                    img
                }
            };
```

и ошибка при компиляции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предоставили бы [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :) А так, у вас в коде есть место для отлова всех исключений? Т.е. стартовый код и внутри него try/catch

Comment: @gil9red добавил код